# Not able to observe LiveData in fragment from Repository

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I am trying to observe a Boolean wrapped in LiveData in my fragment from the repository via the view model although I am successfully able to change its value in Repository I am not able to observe in fragment it doesn't change in the fragment.

My Code

Repository

```
 private val postUploaded: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
        
        
postId.let { it ->
                                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Posts").document(it).set(postMap,
                                        SetOptions.merge())
                                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                                            postUploaded.value=true
        }
    }
        
        
        
        @JvmName("getPostUploaded")
            fun getPostUploaded(): MutableLiveData<Boolean> {
                return postUploaded
            }
```

ViewModel

```
class UploadFragmentViewModel(application: Application) :AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val authAppRepository: Repository = Repository(application)
    private val postUploaded: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = authAppRepository.getPostUploaded()


    @JvmName("getPostUploaded")
    fun getPostUploaded(): MutableLiveData<Boolean> {
        return postUploaded
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
mViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory
    .getInstance(Application())).get(UploadFragmentViewModel::class.java)

mViewModel.getPostUploaded().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {

    Log.d("MyTag", "it in upload fragment is $it")

    if (it){
        binding.lottieanim2.visibility=View.VISIBLE

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            run {
                val fragment: Fragment = HomeFragment()
                            activity!!
                                .supportFragmentManager
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                                .commit()

            }
        }, 2000);

    }
})
```

Comment: How have you verified that the value of the MutableLiveData is actually getting changed in your repository? Maybe put a breakpoint in the onSuccessListener to make sure it's actually successful. By the way, your `postDelayed()` call in your Fragment will trigger a crash if the user backs out of the fragment or rotates the screen during the 2 second delay, since `activity` will be null.

Comment: @Tenfour04 actually just under  postUploaded2=true I am printing Log statement which prints true
                                    Log.d("MyTag", "post uploaded = "+postUploaded.value)

Comment: @Tenfour04 it crashed several times I was just trying something else it's changed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you should not return the LiveData from Repository part. Why? Refer this link for the reason (https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-livedata-in-your-repository-there-are-better-options-25a7557b0730)

Repository code

```
@JvmName("getPostUploaded")
    fun getPostUploaded(
        postMap: Any,
        postId: String,
        updateCallback: (Boolean) -> Unit
    ) {
        postId.let { it ->
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Posts").document(it).set(
                postMap,
                SetOptions.merge()
            ).addOnSuccessListener {
                updateCallback(true)
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel Code

```
private var authRepository: AuthRepository = AuthRepository()
private val _postUploadLiveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
var postUploadLiveData: LiveData<Boolean> = _postUploadLiveData
fun getPostUploaded(
    postMap: Any,
    postId: String
) {
    authRepository.getPostUploaded(postMap, postId) { response ->
        if (response) {
            _postUploadLiveData.postValue(response)
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am using one MutableLiveData (_postUploadLiveData) whose value can be changed inside viewmodel only (beacause it is private) and the other LiveData (postUploadLiveData) which is public and assign the MutableLiveData value and will be observe by activity or fragment and are immutable.

Now call this ViewModel's getPostUploaded function and pass the two variables postMap and postId and observe postUploadLiveData live data

Comment: While LiveData from a repository may not be the best pattern to use, it still works. If they migrate to a different pattern without finding the original issue, they will still have the same issue. By the way, there is no such thing as immutable LiveData. It's "live" after all. LiveData is read-only, not immutable.